# Why did phpMyAdmin stop working after upgrading Ubuntu to 22.04?

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-22.04

Just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and now my phpadmin won't load. I get this following error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'static' (T_STATIC) in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 272

I opened up the file, and here is the specific code in that segment.

```
public function addResource(ResourceInterface $resource): static
{
    if (!$this->trackResources) {
        return $this;
    }

   if ($resource instanceof GlobResource && $this->inVendors($resource->getPrefix())) {
       return $this;
    }

    $this->resources[(string) $resource] = $resource;

   return $this;
}
```

Yesterday before the upgrade, everything was working fine. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: What `phpmyadmin` and `PHP` itself versions do you have?

Comment: I'm running 7.4

Answer (score 12):

Im using php7.4.30 and my fix was upgrading phpmyadmin.

Here is a simple guide:

https://devanswers.co/manually-upgrade-phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 7):

Since version 8.0, PHP allows `static` as a return type for class methods. Apparently your PHP version was downgraded.

Comment: so I need to uninstall php 8

Comment: You have to use at least PHP 8.0, or downgrade phpMyAdmin

Comment: @GrzegorzPietrzak but he has `Symfony` error, not `phpMyAdmin` one, phpMyAdmin does not require `PHP` 8.0 yet, `7.4` for latest version, I believe

Comment: Since version 5.0 PMA uses Symfony components, including DI Container. Looking at the Packagist - it should work with PHP 7.1.3+, but apparently something is not right.

Comment: solved it. Fully upgraded and added extra modules for php 8.1

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's a pain if you are running a PHP version prior to 8, such as 7.*.
Download 5.2 here and install it.

https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/

Completely purge your previous version and secure the directory where you install it (depends on your web server). That Symfony component ruined everything (line 272).

Answer (score 1):

- upgrade php to 8.x
- switch php version in apache:

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
sudo rm php7.4.conf
sudo rm php7.4.load
sudo ln -s ../mods-available/php8.0.load php8.0.load
sudo ln -s ../mods-available/php8.0.conf php8.0.conf
```

at the end, restart apache:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Probably not necessary but just want to add that if you're on PHP 8.1 you need to change above commands to 8.1

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your phpmyadmin version Coz in php 8.* version phpmyadmin 5.* version will be required.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using opcache preloading, you might be suffering from conflicts between phpMyAdmin's Symfony namespaces and those of your own app. My workaround for this is to run phpMyAdmin on a different version of PHP