# Empty page on phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

My problem is that I have an empty page at /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php. apache2 is working (i.e. I get its default page at localhost).  PHP is working; I get the phpinfo page at localhost/phpinfo.php after creating that stub page).  If I run "php index.php" on the phpmyadmin, it doesn't give any obvious errors (as far as I can tell; I'm not an expert on any of this). If I move that phpinfo page into the phpmyadmin directory and rename it index.php, I can see it fine, so apache2 seems to be serving pages from that directory correctly.  But I only see a blank page when I use the normal phpmyadmin/index.php.  Also, if I try to see the code in the browser window, it's blank also.

How I got here: I have a RasPi running Raspian.  I wanted to use it to stream music, and I found this program called "Koel" that looked interesting.  To use it, you're supposed to install apache, php, something called composer, and a few other things.  So,everything was going swimmingly until I reached a point where Koel said it needed php > 8, where as 7.4 is the default for Raspian.  So I installed php 8.2, and got apache to use it (confirmed in phpinfo).  So then I installed and tried to access phpmyadmin so I could create user/db for Koel, but it complained that I needed mysqli (but at least I saw some output from phpmyadmin.  Installed that, and that error went away, but I still had a blank page.  Ran "php index.php" and did see some errors at first, relating to www-data not having access to blowfish.inc.php and another file (forget the name), so I made both of those accessible, and then the error messages for "php index.php" went away, but I still only get a blank page.  Thought this might have something more to do with permissions, so I've been experimenting with changing the owner/permissions on the phpmyadmin files, but no luck.  Lastly, the MariaDB seems to be correct, as far as I know.  It's got a DB called phpmyadmin, and I can log into it with user phpmyadmin/password.  Seems like it should work.  Anyone have any ideas?

I checked the apache2 log, and I get this error at the end:

> [Thu Apr 20 17:22:39.405474 2023] [php:error] [pid 10602] [client 192.168.1.142:61073] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Component\Config\ctype_alpha() in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Config/FileLocator.php:83\nStack trace:\n#0 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Config/FileLocator.php(42): Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator->isAbsolutePath()\n#1 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php(120): Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator->locate()\n#2 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php(94): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader->load()\n#3 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php(23): require_once('...')\n#4 {main}\n  thrown in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Config/FileLocator.php on line 83

I'm not sure what that all means, but I THINK that this ctype_alpha is something that is missing from 8.2.  I never did test phpmyadmin with 7.4 before moving to 8.2, so I rolled back and - sure enough - it works fine with 7.4.  So I think the 8.2 version is messed up.

Comment: I finally gave up. I think it was a problem with PHP 8.2, but can't be sure.  At any rate, I found another program (Navidrome) which does the same thing, and I got it going in about 10 minutes.  Bye Koel.  Thx for your input anyway.

Comment: It looks like you didn't install it properly. Not sure why you were trying it with composer. Please try to install it from your distribution. Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72061079/why-did-phpmyadmin-stop-working-after-upgrading-ubuntu-to-22-04